# Get toggle input value in order to switch page view with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a web photoGallery and I want to add a toggle input button to switch between display Albums or Display all photos. I need to get the value of the input with jQuery and do a AjaxCall in order to reload the content with the appropriate display.

I have this

```js
<script>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("#VistaToggle").toggle(function () {
                $("#valor1").text($(this).val())
                {% comment %}if ($(this).val() == "Vista Álbum"){
                    $("#valor1").text("Vista Álbum")
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#valor1").text("Vista Fotos")
                }{% endcomment %}
            })
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" align="center">
        <input id="VistaToggle" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size=="large" data-on="Vista Álbum" data-off="Vista Fotos"  data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
        <p id="valor1">El estado actual es:</p>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to catch the change event of the toggle input and update the value of text.

Comment: If you are trying to catch the change event, why are you trying to use the `toggle` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the change event, do so.  And since your text is on your checkbox as data attributes, you can reference those in your script as well.

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#VistaToggle").on('change', function () {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("#valor1").text(this.getAttribute('data-on'));
      } else {
        $("#valor1").text(this.getAttribute('data-off'));
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" align="center">
        <input id="VistaToggle" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size=="large" data-on="Vista Álbum" data-off="Vista Fotos"  data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
        <p id="valor1">El estado actual es:</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works for a simple checkbox input, but it doesn't work for my code. Maybe because I'm using a bootstrap class for the input toggle button?